# jsonArray.length() not given the right number of array element

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am using org.json parser.
I am getting a json array using `jsonObject.getJSONArray(key)`.
The problem is the `jsonArray.length()` is returning me `1` and my json array have 2 elements, what am I doing wrong?

```
String key= "contextResponses";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
Object value = jsonObject.get("contextResponses");  

if (value instanceof JSONArray){
  JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
  System.out.println("array length is: "+jsonArray.length());/*the result is 1! */
}
```

Here is my json:

```
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "ENTITY",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "ENTITY3",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "ATTR1",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, the result is `1` what do you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is perfectly normal, since the `JSONArray` contains only one `JSONObject`. To get the `length` of the `JSONObject` you're looking for, use this:

```
// Get the number of keys stored within the first JSONObject of this JSONArray
jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).length(); 

//----------------------------
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    // The first & only JSONObject of this JSONArray
    {
      // 2 JSONObjects
      "contextElement" : {
          // 1
      },
      "statusCode" : {
          // 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array contains exactly one object therefore the length is correct:

```
"contextResponses" : [
  {
     ... content of the object ...
  }
]
```